# Setting breakpoint on OLE32 API's in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, breakpoints, ole

I'm trying to set a breakpoint on CLSIDFromProgID while debugging Excel (32 bit) as I'm looking into an add-in issue.  So far I haven't figured out how to do it on Win10.  Both the Visual Studio (17) debugger and WinDbg say they have loaded the symbols for ole32.dll.  I've tried:

in WinDbg:

```
ole32!CLSIDFromProgID
ole32!_CLSIDFromProgID
ole32!_CLSIDFromProgID@8
CLSIDFromProgID
_CLSIDFromProgID
_CLSIDFromProgID@8
```

in visual studio:

```
{,,ole32.dll}CLSIDFromProgID
{,,ole32.dll}_CLSIDFromProgID
{,,ole32.dll}_CLSIDFromProgID@8
CLSIDFromProgID
_CLSIDFromProgID
_CLSIDFromProgID@8
```

In some cases it seemed to set a breakpoint but it was actually in some other module so that didn't help.  If I view the exported CLSIDFromProgID in ole32.dll on Win10 I see:

```
CLSIDFromProgID (forwarded to api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.CLSIDFromProgID)
```

When I use the DBH tool included with WinDbg to list the symbols in ole32.pdb, the only CLSIDFromProgID symbol I see is:

```
_imp__CLSIDFromProgID
```

while debugging Excel and having already executed the code which calls CLSIDFromProgID I don't see module api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-0.dll loaded.

Anyone successful putting a breakpoint of any of these forwarded API's?

[Edit]

By the way, if you want Excel to call CLSIDFromProgID you can enter the following in a cell:

```
=RTD("MyBogus.ProgId", "", "Foo")
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Those minwin forwarders make it convoluted, the function actually lives in combase.dll

Comment: @Hans Passant: if you phrase that in the form of an answer I can mark it as the answer as I think this is solving my problem:)  Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully somebody will post an answer that shows how to actually discover this fact.  I merely happened to know by accident.  I suspect that the "loader snaps" feature can dig this out, try it.